# numpy broadcast of vectorized function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a function `f` that compute the inner-product-like value of 2 vectors (the function is symmetrical, so `f(x, y) = f(y, x)`). It take 2 1d array of same size and output a single value. Now I have a data matrix `X` of shape `(n, d)` (each row represents an input vector), and I would like to compute a matrix `K` with shape `(n, n)` such that `K[i][j] = f(X[i], X[j])`. One way to do this is to use the following code.

```py
import numpy as np
# ... some other code
K = np.zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        K[i][j] = f(X[i], X[j])
```

This works, but it's neither elegant nor performant.
Another way to do this is using `vectorize` from numpy

```py
import numpy as np
# ... some other code
vf = np.vectorize(f, signature="(n),(n)->()")

# this does not work (output shape (n,))
#K = vf(X, X)

# this works (output shape (n, n))
K = vf(X, X[: np.newaxis])

# this also works (output shape (n, n), result same as above)
#K = vf(X[: np.newaxis], X)
```

If we put in an array of `(n, d)` and another array of `(n, d)`, it will output an 1 dimensional array of `(n,)`, essentially taking each of the `n` rows of both matrix as input and thus produce `n` output. However, if we transform it to `X[: np.newaxis]`, which has shape `(n, 1, d)`, it works, but why it works?

I already checked [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) and [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/c-api/generalized-ufuncs.html), but still can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

We can illustrate this `broadcasting` with add:

```
In [111]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [112]: x
Out[112]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [113]: x + x[:,None]
Out[113]: 
array([[[ 0,  2,  4,  6],
        [ 4,  6,  8, 10],
        [ 8, 10, 12, 14]],

       [[ 4,  6,  8, 10],
        [ 8, 10, 12, 14],
        [12, 14, 16, 18]],

       [[ 8, 10, 12, 14],
        [12, 14, 16, 18],
        [16, 18, 20, 22]]])
In [114]: _.shape
Out[114]: (3, 3, 4)
In [115]: (x + x[:,None]).sum(axis=-1)
Out[115]: 
array([[12, 28, 44],
       [28, 44, 60],
       [44, 60, 76]])
```

The broadcasting goes: (3,4) and (3,1,4) => (1,3,4) and (3,1,4) => (3,3,4).  Then we sum on the last axis to get (3,3)

Doing the same thing as you did:

```
In [116]: vf = np.vectorize(lambda a,b:(a+b).sum(), signature="(n),(n)->()")
In [117]: vf(x, x[:,None])
Out[117]: 
array([[12, 28, 44],
       [28, 44, 60],
       [44, 60, 76]])
```

But as noted, `np.vectorize` is not a speed tool, especially when using `signature`:

```
In [118]: timeit (x + x[:,None]).sum(axis=-1)
13.8 µs ± 363 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [119]: timeit vf(x, x[:,None])
278 µs ± 7.68 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Without adding the dimension to the 2nd `x`:

```
In [120]: vf(x, x)
Out[120]: array([12, 44, 76])
In [121]: (x + x).sum(axis=-1)
Out[121]: array([12, 44, 76])
```

Comment: I saw your answer but had already written a lot of text already so posted mine.

Answer (score 1):

Another example in addition to @hpaulj's answer

Broadcasting can be used to vectorize your code efficiently. Let's take an example. I have an array (10,2) and I want to take the Euclidean distance between each of the points.

```
X = np.random.uniform(-5,5,(10,2))
```

One way to do this is to broadcast my complete formula for Euclidean distance using NumPy function which supports broadcasting.

```
np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(np.subtract(X[:,None,:], X[None,:,:])), axis=-1))

#This returns a (10,10) matrix, with euclidean distance of each of the 10 points to the other
```

Similarly, another thing you could do is vectorize your function to behave similar to a numpy function and support broadcasting.

```
def euclidean(point1, point2):
    return ((point1[0]-point2[0])**2 + (point1[1]-point2[1])**2)**(1/2)

euclidean_v = np.vectorize(euclidean, signature="(n),(n)->()")

euclidean_v(X[:,None,:], X[None,:,:])

#Again returns a (10,10)
```

In both cases -

```
         |--- (10,1,2)--|
(10,2)---|              |---(10,10,2)--->(10,10)
         |--- (1,10,2)--|
```